# Any difference between [col] in ('single element') and [col] = 'single element'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm refactoring a collegues' old SQL code and noticed in a few places a where clause of the form `where [SomeCol] in ('XYZ')`. I'm assuming that this is just a result of quick copy-paste from other places in the code with more values in the brackets (`where [SomeCol] in ('ABC', 'DEF', 'XYZ')`) and replacing them with `[SomeCol] = 'XYZ'`, even if only for the sake of neatness.

Just wanted to be absolutely sure though that the two statements are functionally equivilant - I would assume that `[SomeCol] = 'XYZ'` is a little (likely unoticably) more efficient, but don't want to find out later I'm tripping over some obscure functionality that will produce different results.

Comment: Take a look at execution plan. For my examples it's one and the same.

Comment: They are equivalent in every way. No difference in results and no difference in performance either. If you check the execution plan you will see that your  `[SomeCol] in ('XYZ')` is executed as `[SomeCol] = 'XYZ'` so you will not make any difference by changing it.

Comment: @Kai . . . The one difference is maintainability.  If you may be adding and removing values, then the `in` form is safer.  You don't have to worry about someone doing changing `x = 'a' and y = 'c'` to `x = 'a' or x = 'b' and y = 'c'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should be the same operationally. I've sometimes done the IN when I had a single value at the start but suspected in the future other values could be required. That makes it easier to add the new values without changing the structure of the the statement. Just a guess at the "why".

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent.

For values less than 63 in the IN list, SQL Server expands the IN list to multiple ORs. For example,

```
[SomeCol] IN (1,2,3,4)
```

will be evaulated as

```
([SomeCol]=1 or [SomeCol]=2 or [SomeCol]=3 or [SomeCol]=4)
```

Hence in this case, there would be no ORs hence both are equivalent.

Comment: Do you by any change recall where you got that information from? I would be very interested in articles about the inner workings of the MSSQL query optimizer, so if it's a public source PLEASE share the link :-)

Comment: @PaulGroke - I'm not sure it's documented anywhere. But it's kind of obvious that something of the sort is going on if you misspell `SomeCol` - you'll get one error message per element in the `IN`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I'm pretty sure that's an artefact of the parser and doesn't say anything about what the query optimizer would have done with the query if it would have ever seen it.

Comment: Would also like to know where you got the 63 figure from - just tried a purposefully erroneous `in` list with hundreds of values (as per Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment), no evidence from the error list that the behaivour changes above this number.

Comment: Just checked 2 execution plans - one with an `in` query with 20 elements, one with 200. Both seem to be evaluated as a chain of OR statements, regardless of length.

Comment: @Kai I need to dig up where I came across the number but I believe, above 63, it maintains the list in a temp table and uses that to help execution. Do you see any additional table scan in your execution plan with 200?

Comment: Nope, no additional table plans, structure of the execution plan in XML view appears identical (just longer for the 200-element one)